# Difference between ne_chunk from NLTK and stanza for NER?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Sorry this is my first question!

I am starting named entity recognition on python and have used ne_chunk and stanza.

I would like to know what the difference is between their pre-trained models for the NER.  How do they recognize named entities?

Answer (score 3):

**STANZA**

1. The Stanford NLP Group recently released Stanza, a new python natural language processing toolkit.
2. It contains support for running various accurate natural language processing tools on 60+ languages and for accessing the Java Stanford CoreNLP software from Python.
3. A new collection of **biomedical** and **clinical English model packages** are now available, supporting **syntactic analysis** and **named entity recognition (NER)** from **biomedical literature text** and **clinical notes**.
4. Stanza supports Python 3.6 or later

**Advantages**

- From raw text to annotations: Stanza features a fully neural pipeline which takes raw text as input, and produces annotations to any specific purpose.
- Multilingual. Stanza architectural design is language-agnostic and data-driven, which allows us to release models supporting 60+ languages, by training the pipeline on the Universal Dependencies (UD) treebanks and other multilingual corpora.
- State-of-the-art performance: Stanza neural pipeline adapts well to text of different genres, achieving state-of-the-art or competitive performance at each step of the pipeline.
  [image]

- Install required libraries With pip, you can easily install package

  ```
  pip install stanza
  ```
- Importing the required libraries

  ```
  import stanza
  ```

  it will download the below links

  ```
  #http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanza/1.1.0/en/default.zip
  #https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/stanza-resources/master/resources_1.1.0.json
  nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,ner') # initialize English neural pipeline

  doc = nlp("""John F. Kennedy International Airport is an international airport in Queens, New York, USA, and one of the primary airports serving New York City.""") # run annotation over a sentence

  print(*[f'entity: {ent.text}\ttype: {ent.type}' for sent in doc.sentences for ent in sent.ents], sep='\n')


  Initializing
  2021-01-21 11:36:23 INFO: Loading these models for language: en (English):

   =========================
   | Processor | Package   |
   -------------------------
   | tokenize  | ewt       |
   | ner       | ontonotes |
   =========================

   2021-01-21 11:36:23 INFO: Use device: cpu
   2021-01-21 11:36:23 INFO: Loading: tokenize
   2021-01-21 11:36:23 INFO: Loading: ner
   2021-01-21 11:36:26 INFO: Done loading processors!
  ```

**STANZA Output**

```
    entity: John F. Kennedy International Airport   type: FAC
    entity: Queens  type: GPE
    entity: New York    type: GPE
    entity: USA type: GPE
    entity: one type: CARDINAL
    entity: New York City   type: GPE
```

**ne_chunk**

1. POS tagged sentences are parsed into chunk trees with normal chunking but the trees labels can be entity tags in place of chunk phrase tags
2. NLTK uses these chunks as part of a tree-like system to do its tagging, though it also has a tagger which follows an IOB system.
3. NLTK has already a pre-trained named entity chunker which can be used using ne_chunk() method in the nltk.chunk module.

Here are some code snippets explaining how to use both, and how to convert between them:

```
from nltk.chunk import conlltags2tree, tree2conlltags 
from nltk import pos_tag 
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk
```

where these models are trained on the CoNLL (from the CoNLL conference) corpus in NLTK. Since we already did our tokenizing, POS-tagging and chunking, all we need to do for the tree-based tagging is to use the conlltags2tree

```
sentence = """John F. Kennedy International Airport is an international airport in Queens, New York, USA, and one of the primary airports serving New York City."""

ne_tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))) 
ne_in_sent = []
for subtree in ne_tree:
if type(subtree) == Tree: # If subtree is a noun chunk, i.e. NE != "O"
    # print(subtree.label())
    # print(subtree.leaves())
    ne_label = subtree.label()
    ne_string = " ".join([token for token, pos in subtree.leaves()])
    ne_in_sent.append((ne_string, ne_label))

print(ne_in_sent)
```

**NLTK Output**

```
[('John', 'PERSON'), ('Kennedy International Airport', 'PERSON'), ('Queens', 'GPE'), ('New York', 'GPE'), ('USA', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('New York City', 'GPE')]
```

in my point of view **Stanza** is Advanced than **NLTK**

Because Sometimes ambiguity/confusion
Example :John F. Kennedy (Airport versus Person)
**Stanza NER Identified entity**: John F. Kennedy International Airport type: FAC (FACILITY Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.)

Stanza identified correctly

**NLTK NER Identified entity**: ('John', 'PERSON'), ('Kennedy International Airport', 'PERSON')

**NLTK** Partially identified.

Also I cross verified with AllenNLP

**AllenNLP**

```
import allennlp
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bert-base-srl-2020.09.03.tar.gz")
document = """John F. Kennedy International Airport is an international airport in Queens, New York, USA, and one of the primary airports serving New York City. """
def convert_results(allen_results):
  ents = set()
  for word, tag in zip(allen_results["words"], allen_results["tags"]):
    if tag != "O":
      ent_position, ent_type = tag.split("-")
      if ent_position == "U":
        ents.add((word,ent_type))
      else:
        if ent_position == "B":
          w = word
        elif ent_position == "I":
          w += " " + word
        elif ent_position == "L":
          w += " " + word
          ents.add((w,ent_type))
  return ents

def allennlp_ner(document):
  return convert_results(predictor.predict(sentence=document))

allennlp_ner(document)
```

**AllenNLP output**

```
{('John F. Kennedy International Airport', 'LOC'),  ('New York', 'LOC'),  ('New York City', 'LOC'),  ('Queens', 'LOC'),  ('USA', 'LOC')}
```